Split variable into several variables
I have a dataset in Stata which looks as follows
ID    Product     Region                        Sales
001   JSF045      East~West~North               45~78~14
002   JSF056      East~West                     56~35
003   GWW1        West~North~South~South East   11~16~45~36  

I want to split the Region and Sales variables into separate variables  (separation at ~). Each row will have different number of regions and sales figures but for every row, a region will correspond to a sales figure. I present below how I want the final data to look.
I want the final data to look like as below
ID    Product     Region            Sales
001   JSF045      East              45
001   JSF045      West              78
001   JSF045      North             14
002   JSF056      East              56
002   JSF056      West              35
003   GWW1        West              11
003   GWW1        North             16 
003   GWW1        South             45  
003   GWW1        South East        36  


For Stata questions, please use Stata terminology, so variables not columns.

* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str3 ID str6 Product str27 Region str11 Sales
"001" "JSF045" "East~West~North"             "45~78~14"   
"002" "JSF056" "East~West"                   "56~35"      
"003" "GWW1"   "West~North~South~South East" "11~16~45~36"
end

split Region, parse("~")
split Sales, parse("~") destring 
drop Region Sales 

reshape long Region Sales, i(ID) j(which)
drop if missing(Region)

list, sepby(ID)

     +--------------------------------------------+
     |  ID   which   Product       Region   Sales |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  1. | 001       1    JSF045         East      45 |
  2. | 001       2    JSF045         West      78 |
  3. | 001       3    JSF045        North      14 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  4. | 002       1    JSF056         East      56 |
  5. | 002       2    JSF056         West      35 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  6. | 003       1      GWW1         West      11 |
  7. | 003       2      GWW1        North      16 |
  8. | 003       3      GWW1        South      45 |
  9. | 003       4      GWW1   South East      36 |
     +--------------------------------------------+

